# How do I create something that counts the number of new items between two lists?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a function that would compare two columns and return the number of new items on the second list. How would I do this?

As an example, let's say I have two lists:

List A:
a
b
c
d
e
f
g

List B:
a
c
d
f
h
i
j

How would I get it to return the number of new items that aren't on list 1, but are on list 2? I'd be looking for it to return the value of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both lists are in columns you can use either of the two formulas (see the screenshot below). The one with SUMPRODUCT is preferred for older versions of excel.
[image: Compare two lists]